# Using kooaba from an iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to make use of kooaba image recognition library in my iPhone application. Can anybody tell me how can I send a query to kooaba API and how can I use kooaba API to recognize the image from my application. Where to I have to send my photo using kooaba?

Answer (score 1):

To use the kooaba service you first need to have an API key.  You can sign up for a key and learn more about using the API here:
http://www.kooaba.com/technology/api/

To send your photo(s) to the service you'll want to use NSURLConnection and NSURLRequest API's.  You can read about using them in the [URL Loading System](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html) documentation.

Apple also demonstrates using the `PUT` method in HTTP in this sample code: [SimpleURLConnections](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SimpleURLConnections/index.html)